Json error: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent on Aws-bitnami
Inquiries regarding logs in the following format are probably the most common due to json errors related to WordPress.

[Thu Jul 25 13:00:50.367263 2024] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 26574:tid 140437025085120] [client xxx.it.is.myIp:50810] AH01071: Got error '; PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/MY-WEB-1stDOMAIN-FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php on line 1831; PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/MY-WEB-1stDOMAIN-FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php on line 1831;

In my case, the error log is related to 'the Invalid JSON Error'(or 'Receiving JSON error when trying to upload images'). I already know some general advice for solving this problem. And I tried running it.
For example:

Consider plugin conflicts on your Wordpress. So I turned off/deactivate all plugins and review them one by one.

Consider the unique link(Permalinks) of the post on your Wordpress setting panel. So I tried changing from a general Permalinks to a Permalinks of the post title format(or reverse).

Remove whitespace in PHP code. So I tried removing spaces from my custom function files(ex: function.php of theme child). And I even tried manually replacing all WordPress resource files through FTP.

Regenerate WordPress .htaccess File. So I regenerated .htaccess by Wordpress' default.

and etc...


But it wasn't resolved. So I thought this was a problem with the web server's absolute path or redirection. This is because this problem occurred after migrating to the Aws Bitnami server.
As those of you who have used it know, bitnami's LAMP service currently provides a web root to the '/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/' path. It means 'htdocs' is of a base web directory for a static ip. And in 'httpd.conf' or 'bitnami.conf', this default/base directory is received as web http. And then host user can be distributed to multisites' domain directories through 'vhost.conf'. (MY-WEB-1stDOMAIN-FOLDER, MY-WEB-2ndDOMAIN-FOLDER, MY-WEB-3rdDOMAIN-FOLDER...)
And between this structure, URLs are processed by intervening in the certificated domain address through 'ssl.conf'.
So,

I also reviewed these files that process the multiple domains URL and address several times. (There is currently no problem accessing each folder/web of each wordpress screen using these multiple domains.)

Of course, I also applied all permissions for the WordPress directory, in which bitnami engineer suggest. (ex: chown -R bitnami:daemon 'htdocs' or 'MY-WEB-1stDOMAIN-FOLDER')


However, I cannot eliminate errors that appear in 'Receiving JSON error when trying to upload images' or in that error.logs file.
This error usually occurs when editing a WordPress post. This doesn't happen with every post. It happens on some posts and not on others (I've heard it's an issue related to WordPress's Gutenberg block editor). However, regardless of Gutenberg, that Json errors occur 100% when uploading images.
There is no problem editing posts, uploading and saving images' result. That error just pops up.
Some recommend the classic editor plugin of Wordpress, but I don't want to deal with this problem that way.
I can't help but think that it is a design flaw of Editor in WordPress(or bitnami?) that the error does not go away even after various reviews and actions. what do you think? (Is there a way to solve this problem by adjusting/changing Bitnami’s path?)
Please note, I did not use the (multi) WordPress app provided by Bitnami package, but I manually installed each WordPress in each folder on the LAMP instance. (In addition to WordPress 6.6.1, which I installed myself, all versions PHP 8.x, MariaDB 10.x... provided by AWS are the latest versions.)
Thank you in advance for your comment.

PS: I don't know how this issue is related, but when using the Gutenberg block editor, it seems that the Json error appears if using the margin as an empty sentence block. (Apart from Json issue that occur when uploading images)

I solved my issue above. I am leaving detailed records of the solution process for those who encounter similar problems.
Usage environment:
I manually installed WordPress three times in each folder for three separate domain sites using the AWS Lightsail Bitnami LAMP service. (This is not the WordPress bundled system provided by AWS Lightsail. For my customizing easy, DB and WordPress are installed myself in LAMP.)
bitnami.conf :
# Default Virtual Host configuration.
# Let Apache know we're behind a SSL reverse proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on`enter code here`

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
</VirtualHost>
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf"

vhost.conf :
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
    ServerName domain-1st
    ServerAlias domain-1st
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/folder-domain-1st
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/folder-domain-1st">
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
    ServerName domain-1st
    ServerAlias domain-1st
    DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/folder-domain-1st
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/domain-1st.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/domain-1st.key"
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/folder-domain-1st">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

Note: domain-1st, domain-2nd, domain-3rd.. are all unique domain names.
Symptoms of my Issue :

When a post is saved (or temporarily saved),
'Updating Failed … not a valid JSON response'

When uploading image,
'The response is not a valid JSON response.'


My actions on this issue :


Consider plugin conflicts on your Wordpress.
Consider the unique link(Permalinks) of the post on your Wordpress setting panel.
Remove whitespace in PHP code.
Manually replacing all WordPress resource files through FTP.
Review .conf files that process the multiple domains URL and address several times.
Check permissions for the WordPress directory, in which bitnami engineer suggest.


At this point I posted a question here. And I found and debugged some additional symptoms.


Since this symptom mainly appears in large posts, I tried debugging by removing each block-Gutenberg. Are Json error occurring in complex blocks of Gutenberg? Are there Json error in image blocks? What I discovered from this debugging was that it was not a problem with a specific block, but rather with the size of the pose.


Conclusion of solution
Bundled WordPress served by Aws Lightsail automatically includes PHP-related structural permissions. For example,
<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/wordpress.sock|fcgi://wordpress-fpm" timeout=300>
    </Proxy>
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
         SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://wordpress-fpm"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfDefine>

Paths such as 'proxy:fcgi' or 'wordpress.sock' shown above are permission measures included in such bundles. However, I mentioned above that I did not install WordPress through the bundle.
WordPress basically uses PHP's own temp folder when uploading large-sized posts or images. The following code is known, but it does not work, at least in Aws Lightsail LAMP, or requires PHP's own temp.
define( 'WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/tmp/');

However, PHP's own temp defaults to root:root permission. So I had had to change this permission. With ‘root:daemon’. 'daemon' is bitnami's general-user permission.
The following line is the conclusion to resolve all of the above processes.
sudo chown -R root:daemon /opt/bitnami/php/tmp

WordPress is a very advanced, user-centric content tool. This is the result of their efforts to make it very easy. However, as relatively easy as it is, it creates complex problems that are difficult to find behind the scenes.
